# Failed to load plugin libgazebo_ros2_control.so: libgazebo_ros2_control.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: ros2, gazebo-11

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi. Sorry for all mistakes, English is not my native language. I'm trying to spawn my robot in gazebo. The world is loaded successfully but model of robot itself is not and I have following error in terminal.

```
[gazebo-1] [Err] [Plugin.hh:212] Failed to load plugin libgazebo_ros2_control.so: libgazebo_ros2_control.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1669073669.505081456] [urdf_spawner]: Spawn status: SpawnEntity: Successfully spawned entity [minicar]
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-4]: process has finished cleanly [pid 10576]
```

I've installed my gazebo with ros2 foxy using desktop installation, after receiving this error first time I checked if this file can be found in /opt/ros/foxy/lib folder and there are no such file. I reinstall gazebo with following command

```
sudo apt install ros-foxy-gazebo-pkg
```

Didn't work ether. If first and last time than I launched it environment has been sourced with:

```
source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash
```

so I, honestly speaking, have no idea where the problem can be. Appreciate any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28579/failed-to-load-plugin-libgazebo_ros2_control.so:-libgazebo_ros2_control.so:-cannot-open-shared-object-file:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [Vincent](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/116526/vincent/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2022-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Problem solved with sudo apt install ros-foxy-gazebo-ros2-control

---

Originally posted by [Vincent](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/116526/vincent/) with karma: 1 on 2022-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0